# Solving with Newton's Optimization Method

Tags: convex-optimization

I am aware of how to implement the [Newton's method for minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method_in_optimization) for a smooth analytic function.

I am also aware of log-barrier for constraint minimization.

Now, I am looking to solve the the minimization of L-2 norm with L-1 regularization. Thus, I want to solve,

$$ \text{minimize}_\beta \  ||\textbf{y}-\textbf{X}\beta||_2 $$
$$ \text{subject to} \ ||\beta||_1 \le T  $$

$\beta \in R^p$, $X \in R^{n \times p}$. T is a known constant. How do I incoperate the L-1 norm in constraint minimization.

Comment: What's your purpose here? There are lots of existing tools to do this. If you just want to solve a particular problem, you might as well use one of those.

Comment: Actually, I am wanting to learn about newton's method for minimization adapted for constraint-optimization (log-barrier).

Comment: Then you should probably be consulting textbooks, like Boyd & Vandenberghe, Bertsekas, Renegar...

Comment: actually, I did finally solve this using 2^p linear equations constraints as mentioned in sec 2.6 of http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/Documents/2005_Notes_Lasso.pdf. Although it also mentions other better solutions, but I got the point now....and thanks for all the help

Comment: That looks like a nice report indeed...